# Resumable exceptions: any real-life scenario?

Tags: exception, abap

As the topic states, I can hardly imagine, where and when to use resumable exceptions in a real life example and which effective advantage we might get by the usage of them.

What I can imagine is, a subsystem is connected, let's say via RFC to a session, which is held open. The subsystem has to pass some shopflor-data to sap, let us say, in an usual way, in the frequency of any weight/piece/liter, which is processed.

Somehow something fails.

I can get all of this done, without the use of  a resumable exceptions, so, besides that this exception seems to keep track of the entire context( what does not seem to be a NEW feature), does anybody have a clue, what this is really all about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-resumable exception is an error of the kind "Something went wrong here, and I can't continue running the program as desired any more. TILT." The caller just has to deal with that.

A resumable exception still tells the caller that something went wrong, but it defers the decision if the program can be continued to the caller. I expect there to be only a few scenarios where this might be useful. Mass updates might be one scenario: "You wanted me to update both the material price and the text; I've changed the price, but the text in language ZH doesn't exist. I don't know whether you'd like to abort the operation entirely (RETURN) or keep the updated price and disregard the missing text (RESUME)."

Comment: Thx, vwegert. In terms of transactional processing this now seems really obvious. Especially, that the caller may decide. It might also be helpful in framework-development, where clients using third-party-frameworks can decide, what to do... I suppose.